# Flask redirects to wrong view when redirecting to index

Tags: python, flask

I keep running into this strange issue that I can't seem to figure out a solution for. I cannot copy and show all of my code in it's entirety here, but I will try to outline the general structure of my flask app to present my issue.

(Let's ignore all of the content in the */static* folder and my helper modules)

I have 3 main views, let's call them viewA, viewB, and index:

```
viewA.html
viewB.html
index.html
```

viewA and viewB both display two forms, but with different content (i.e. viewA displays form1 & form2, and viewB also displays form1 & form2).

A simplified version of my script code is as follows:

```
#imports
from flask import Flask, render_template, session, redirect, url_for, request
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
#etc. etc.

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'blah blah blah'

manager = Manager(app)
bootstrap = Bootstrap(app)
moment = Moment(app)

class FormOne(FlaskForm):
    sample_field = StringField('Sample Field:')


class FormTwo(FlaskForm):
    other_field = StringField('Other Field:', validators=[Required()])
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')


class UploadToA(FlaskForm):
    content= StringField('Content to send to view A:', validators=[Required()])
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')


class UploadToB(FlaskForm):
    content= StringField('Content to send to view A:', validators=[Required()])
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')


@app.route('/ViewA', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def view_a():
    """
    A lot of data manipulation
    """

    form1 = FormOne()
    form2 = FormTwo()

    if request.method == 'GET':
        """
        populate forms with content
        """

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form2.validate_on_submit();
            """
            clear session variables
            """
            return redirect(url_for('index'), code=302)
    return render_template('viewA.html', form1=form1, form2=form2)

@app.route('/ViewB', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def view_b():
    """
    A lot of data manipulation
    """

    form1 = FormOne()
    form2 = FormTwo()

    if request.method == 'GET':
        """
        populate forms with content
        """
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form2.validate_on_submit();
            """
            clear session variables
            """

            return redirect(url_for('index'), code=302)
    return render_template('viewB.html', form1=form1, form2=form2)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    """
    Some data manipulation
    """

    formA = UploadToA()
    formB = UploadToB()

    if formA.validate_on_submit()':
        """
        pull content from form A
        create some session variables
        """

        return redirect(url_for('view_a'))
    if formB.validate_on_submit()':
        """
        pull content from form B
        create some session variables
        """

        return redirect(url_for('view_b'))
    return render_template('index.html', formA=formA, formB=formB)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager.run()
```

Now the issue at hand I am having here is that for some strange reason when I'm in '*viewA.html*' and I submit my form, I SHOULD be redirected back to '*index.html*' but for some strange reason it redirects me to '*viewB.html*'. Furthermore, the opposite also holds true: when i'm in '*viewB.html*' and I submit my form, I SHOULD also be redirected back to '*index.html*' but it redirects me to '*viewA.html*'. Yet, if I am in either viewA or viewB, I have no issues of going back to the index view if I manually enter the url into my browser.

Any ideas as to why I might be running into this issue?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: UPDATE: actually when I'm in viewA.html and submit form2, it redirects me to viewB.html instead of index.html. Yet, when i'm in viewB.html and submit form2, there are no issues and it redirects me to index.html.

Answer (score 1):

I have finally figured out the source of my problem. It turns out that in my '*viewA.html*' template file, I had the following in my *< form >* tag:

```
<form class="form form-horizontal" method="post" role="form" action="{{url_for('index')}}">
```

And the problem all lies in that last part:

```
action="{{url_for('index')}}"
```

As a result, everytime I would submit *form2* in *viewA.html* it would create a post request for my index page rather than a post request for the *viewA.html* page (which caused a redirect to the wrong view). Thus, by simply removing the action attribute (*action="{{url_for('index')}}"*), I was able to solve my problem!

Answer (score 0):

Since the full code isn't here, I can't confirm this for sure, but what I *think* is happening is this:

1. You open form A
2. You submit form A
3. It sends a redirect to /index
4. It sends a redirect to /FormB

```
if formB.validate_on_submit():
    return redirect(url_for('view_b'))
```

This is probably sending a redirect to View B. Try changing that last line to something like `return something_else` and seeing if it sends that after submitting form A.

Comment: thanks for the response! Yes your idea of flow is correct, but what I don't understand is why between steps 3 & 4 it automatically sends a redirect to /FormB?
i.e.:
1. I'm in viewA, I submit form2 in /viewA
2. I should be redirected to /index (but instead I am immediately redirected to /viewB without me first hitting the submit button for form B in the index view) - This is what I can't seem to figure out why?

And to your second part, even when I change the redirect to be:
'if formB.validate_on_submit():
    return redirect(url_for('different_view'))'
I get the issue

Comment: @DGav After entering `/index`, `formB.validate_on_submit()` results in `True` which causes it to redirect. I think. Otherwise I don't see how this is possible

Comment: @HyperNeautrino You're right. I've editted my comment above to explain more thoroughly, but why would it immediately evaluate to true if I haven't had the chance to submit that form once being redirected to /index? It's like it's getting automatically submitted for me...